# About event handle-function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my program, I write like this:

```
function handleFuc( event ){
  var a = event.pageX;
  var b = event.pageY;
  var tempdiv = document.createElement("div");
  tempdiv.onmouseout = function(){
    var x = event.pageX;    // 1
    var y = event.pageY;    //
  }
}
var div = document.getElementById( "id" );
div.onmouseover = function(){
  handleFuc( event );
}
```

Now, in function `handleFuc`, how could I distinguish the two "event"?

Comment: You might want to rethink the name of your function. People might take it the wrong way. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
 function handleFuc( event , i=0){
  var a = event.pageX;
  var b = event.pageY;
  var tempdiv = document.createElement("div");
  tempdiv.onmouseout = function(){
    var x = event.pageX;    // 1
    var y = event.pageY;    //
  }
 }
 var div = document.getElementById( "id" );
 div.onmouseover = function(){
   handleFuc( event , 1);
 }
```

So what I did was add another argument to the function, that defaults to 0, and in the second call of the function you set this argument to 1. So if 2nd argument is 0, the 1st event called it, if it is 1, the 2nd one did...

Ladislav